# Angular ng-show not reflecting change to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular controller and a timeout calling a function that is setting a variable that an ng-show relies on.  It seems the variable is successfully being changed, but the html element is still showing up.

The JS in my controller is:

```
setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('showAlert is - ' + $scope.showAlert);
      $scope.showAlert = false;
      console.log('showAlert now is - ' + $scope.showAlert);
      $scope.message = '';
}, 3000);
```

which is happening in the success function of an $http.post call (if that matters.

and the HTML is:

```
<h3 ng-show="showAlert">{[{message}]}</h3>
```

What appears in the console is:

showAlert is - true

showAlert now is - false

So it's being changed successfully, it just doesn't seem the template is following suit.  It is correctly hidden when the page is loaded, and $scope.showAlert is originally set to false.

This seems like a very straightforward example, I don't know why this wouldn't be working.  It acts the same if I put the  tag into a contain  as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you writing {[{ }]}? Did you change the markup configuration?

Comment: If you don't know what I'm talking about then write {{message}}  and test

Comment: I did change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are making changes to the scope after 3 sec by calling settimeout funtion, the DOM might be already loaded and uses the initial value of $scope.showalert, if the value got changed later, inorder to apply that new change, you can try placing  $scope.$apply() at the end of our function.

Comment: this was completely it, and worked.  This is a bit bizarre, I don't entirely understand why it would matter if it was delayed by setTimeout vs if I changed this variable via a button click or something.  Any chance you could explain that?  thanks so much!

Comment: The difference in changing the variable on button click vs this settimeout is, thst the button click will trigger the complete  digest cycle, which means it changes the scope value, tiggers any events based on value changes and apply then in DOM, where as in our case the DOM already got loaded and to apply the change on UI, you need to call  $apply function.